# Jquery OL auto numbering

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create auto numbering OL list with JQuery.
I want to create list lik this

1. apple

   1.1 green apple

   1.2 red apple

   1.3 red apple
2. orange

   2.1 orange juice

   2.2 etc

Help me to create this please)

```
   $('#content-main-text ol:first-child li').each(function(index) {
     $(this).html((index + 1) + '. ' + $(this).html());
   });
```

This code adds number for all LI in my list...

Answer (score 0):

I though it would be easy to find a css property to provide the functionality you want, but I couldn't find anything. This is how you do it with jQuery (but it has some issues):

```
function fn(li,parentPrefix) {
    $(li).children("li").each( function(index) {
        var i = index + 1;
        var myPrefix = parentPrefix ? parentPrefix + "." + i : i;
        $(this).html(myPrefix + " " + $(this).html());
        fn( $(this).children("ol"), myPrefix);
    });
}

var topmostOLs = $("ol").filter(function() { return !$(this).parent().is("li") } )
topmostOLs.each(function() {
    fn(this);
});
```

It finds all topmost `ol` elements and the recursively visits their child lists to add the numbering.

For this to display correctly you have to add the css `ol { list-style: none }` to remove the native css-numbering.

One problem with this is that if you mark the list and copy it, it will copy both the added numbering and the native numbering of the `ol`.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/utuci3/edit (press `preview` at the top left to view the result)